# Google Sheet: is it possible to make a chart's vertical axis' Min and Max values automatically adjust according to the values in the dataset?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I want to have my chart, which displays a range of data that updates periodically, to represent the changes across sampled values in a more zoomed-in form by having the minimum value of the vertical axis match the minimum value in the dataset, and the maximum value accordingly.

I tried inputting a formula referring to the minimum and maximum found values, but it keeps returning that the input must be a number.

Is there any way to make it work like this?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best thing you can do is enlarge your chart with the MAXIMIZE flag

[image: maximize flag]

Comment: That doesn't really do what I look for. It just enlarges the chart area to the entirety of the rectangle, but it doesn't zoom the range of values. Thank you for the suggestion, though.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation. This [Charting Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rRcP1BfABIYSWIxify0P3xZlO5tVFmQF13Ord4SJWe4/) sheet has sample data to show how it works.

The basic idea is to add two points to the data that's being graphed — the minimum and maximum values in the entire dataset.

Then, change the format of those two points so they are invisible. (In the example, I made those points red so it would be clear that the format of those points stays the same even when the data that's graphed changes.)

Double-clicking on a specific data point in the chart brings up the "format data point" settings. (see screenshot)

Feel free to change the start and end dates being graphed (C5 & C6).

[image: Screenshot showing the "format data point" settings]